# strtotime fails to add 30 days in time

Tags: php

My code is:

```
$result = 20201601; //fetched from a source as string

//Convert string to date format 'Y/m/d'

$date1 = substr($result, 0, 4) . '/' . substr($result, 4, 2) . '/' . substr($result, 6, 2); 

echo $date1 . "<br>";

//Add 30 days to it

$date2 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($date1)));

echo $date2;

if ($date2 < date('Y/m/d', strtotime('now')))
{
    //If date fetched ($result) is older than 30 days from today's date, then fetch new date from source
}
```

Code fails to add 30 days at: `date('Y/m/d', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($date1)))`, it gives: `1970/01/30`

Comment: Define "fails".

Comment: it gives: 1970/01/30

Comment: Tell me what is what in `2020/16/01`

Comment: Can you please show us the results of your code and why they would be wrong?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: echo $date2 gives 1970/01/30

Comment: That’s because strtotime doesn’t understand the date format you are passing to it, so it returns 0 - which is the timestamp for 1970/01/01, and then you add 30 days to that …

Comment: how do I convince strtotime to understand my intentions?

Comment: Note: _"Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed."_ (From the [docs on `strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php))

Comment: @vivek_23 while I agree with the sentiment, to be fair, `16` can't be a month so it has to be the day. :)

Comment: And another note from the docs: _"Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2."_

Comment: It'd be much cleaner to use the DateTime functions to parse and then manipulate the date, instead of all this faffing about with strings. Dates are, inherently, not just text. Meddling with them in string format is always fragile and error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$date1 = substr($result, 0, 4) . '/' . substr($result, 4, 2) . '/' . substr($result, 6, 2);
```

to

```
$date1 = substr($result, 0, 4) . '/' . substr($result, 6, 2) . '/' . substr($result, 4, 2);
```

This is needed because your current data is in format `20201601`. A month cannot have a value `16`.

Comment: @ComputerUser Make sure that `16` always a day and not a month in your raw data of `20201601`

Comment: @ComputerUser I hope the format of your raw data follows the format of `yyyyddmm`.